# Assigning Values to a character type string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character

```
char *pro[x]={"A","B","C","D"};
```

I can't initialize 'pro' with these alphabets i have also tried it like this:

```
char *pro[x]={'A','B','C','D'};
```

How can i store these alphabets in this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of `char`, you would want either use

```
char* pro = {'A','B','C','D'};
```

Or

```
char pro[] = {'A','B','C','D'};
```

The way you have it written `char* pro[]` is an array of `char*`. Also note that `char` literals use single quotes, double quotes are for `const char*` literals.

Comment: char pro[] = {'A','B','C','D'};
Is It an array of characters?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is.

Comment: if i want to pass it to a function should i do it like?
void fun(char a)
{
}
in main
for loop till 4
fun(pro[i]);

Comment: Yes you could do that.

Comment: @UsmanRazzaq There are a couple of ways to do it. The one actually used by the compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10383641/722271